# Correlation coefficient significance based on bootstrap distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, bootstrap

There is data $x$ and $y$ which does not come from two dimensional normal distribution. However I would like to perform correlation coefficient test. For this purpose I have created the bootstrap distribution of correlation coefficient $\rho$ of $x$ and $y$. How do I test null hypothesis $H_0: \rho=0$ ?

Answer (score 3):

In a strict sense the answer is that you don't. For a bootstrap test you need to resample from a transformed version of the data, which is changed in such a way that the null-hypothesis is true. This does not seem to be what you have done.

However, you can create a confidence interval (the easiest version would be to look at the 2.5th and 97.5th percentiles for the 95% confidence interval) and see if that confidence interval includes 0.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is what I have done, but wasn;t sure if that is proper thing to do.